# Словарь вместо списка в DjangoRestFramework

Tags: python, django, json, django-rest-framework

На данный момент я получаю JSON данные, в котором если у модели есть поля отношений(ForeignKey), мне выдается список диктов [то как не надо!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kn1jo.png), а нужно просто дикт [то как надо!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWY2b.png) Со слов понять трудновато, простите. Утилита, которая принимает данные категорически не хочет меняться, поэтому мне нужно отдавать ей данные формата как она требует. Заранее благодарен!

Model.py

```py
class MainModelClass(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True,
                             blank=True, verbose_name='title', help_text='description')
    ...


class ProxyHosts(models.Model):
    proxy_hosts = models.ForeignKey(MainModelClass, related_name='proxy_hosts', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Main data', help_text='description')
    host = models.CharField(max_length=255,null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='host', help_text='description')
    ...

class CheckResult(models.Model):
    check_result = models.ForeignKey(ProxyHosts, related_name='check_result', on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True,blank=True, verbose_name='host', help_text='description')



class SearchFor(models.Model):
    search_for = models.ForeignKey(CheckResult, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='search_for', null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='searchFor for', help_text='description')
    tag_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='tagName', help_text='description')
    attribute_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='attributeName', help_text='description')
    attribute_value = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='attributeValue', help_text='description')

    def __str__(self):
        return f"SearchFor for {self.search_for}"


class CheckingValue(models.Model):
    checking_value = models.ForeignKey(CheckResult, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='checking_value', null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='checkingValue for', help_text='description')
    attribute_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='attributeName', help_text='description')
    html = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='html', help_text='description')
    element_value = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='elementValue', help_text='description')

    def __str__(self):
        return f"CheckingValue for {self.checking_value}"
```

serializers.py

```py
class CheckingValueSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CheckingValue
        fields = ["attribute_name", 'html', 'element_value']


class SearchForSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = SearchFor
        fields = ["tag_name", 'attribute_name', 'attribute_value']


class CheckResultSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    search_for = SearchForSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    checking_value = CheckingValueSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = CheckResult
        fields = ["search_for", "checking_value"]

class MainSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    proxy_hosts = ProxyHostsSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = MainModelClass
        fields = [ ... ,'proxy_hosts']

class ProxyHostsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    check_result = CheckResultSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = ProxyHosts
        fields = ['host', ... , 'check_result']
```

view.py

```py
class MainViewSet(ListAPIView):
    queryset = MainModelClass.objects.filter(is_published=True)
    serializer_class = MainSerializer


    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Частично я сделал.
Я немного изменил сериализатор, добавил source=... и у меня получился[вот такой формат данных](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4R9DU.png) Как убрать еще одну скобку, пока не знаю, усложняется тем что это форенкей

serializers.py

```
class CheckingValueSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    attributeName = serializers.CharField(source='all.first.attributeName')
    html = serializers.CharField(source='all.first.html')
    elementValue = serializers.CharField(source='all.first.elementValue')
    class Meta:
        model = CheckingValue
        fields = ["attributeName", 'html', 'elementValue']

class SearchForSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tagName = serializers.CharField(source='all.first.tagName')
    attributeName = serializers.CharField(source='all.first.attributeName')
    attributeValue = serializers.CharField(source='all.first.attributeValue')

    class Meta:
        model = SearchFor
        fields = ["tagName", 'attributeName', 'attributeValue']
```